# Train test split Fastai

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I am using numpy.random.seed() to split the dataset in same order every time I am going to train using keras.

I have a doubt when I am trying fastai, is that numpy.random.seed() function will work same as in keras, where I am using ImageDataBunch.from_folder() function to load the dataset...

If not, what to do to split the dataset in same order every time I load the dataset in fastai

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation of [`from_folder()`](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.data.html#ImageDataBunch.from_folder) there is a `seed` argument that you can use:

```
ImageDataBunch.from_folder(seed=1234)
```